# Multiple external Zookeepers not working with Apache NIFI Cluster

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, apache-nifi, apache-zookeeper, amazon-ecs

Condition 1- I am using Apache NIFI cluster as docker in ECS and running one external Zookeeper in EC2 instance, everything is working fine.

But I want to maintain high availability for Zookeepers as well therefore

Condition 2- I am using Apache NIFI cluster as docker in ECS and running 2 external Zookeeper in different EC2 instances. When both the Zookeepers are up, everything works fine but the moment I bring down one of the Zookeeper, it results in error dialog saying "Cluster connection- This node is currently not connected to the Cluster. Any modifications to the data flow made here will not replicate across the Cluster".
My expectation is, when one Zookeeper goes down, another one should take over so that high availability is maintained. Please suggest what am I doing wrong.
I am using docker environment variable for NIFI as-
NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING = EC2 instance-1 IP:2181,EC2 instance-2 IP:2181
Note: Zookeeper is running in both the EC2 instances in port 2181

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper clusters need an odd number of nodes to ensure that there can be a majority of nodes that can act authoritatively. If you add a third node, that should fix it assuming there are no other issues in your setup.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I ran with 3 zookeepers and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark the answer as resolved when you get a chance so others can easily tell it worked for you.